# Import monaco-editor using Vite 2

Tags: vue.js, rollup, rollupjs, vite

Currently, I have set up a Vite 2 project with `monaco-editor` as a dependency.

Whenever I am trying to use it says that the workers are not imported.

```
editorSimpleWorker.js:454 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unexpected usage
    at EditorSimpleWorker.loadForeignModule (editorSimpleWorker.js:454)
    at webWorker.js:38
```

Since I am using Vite 2 I have assumed that simply specifying the rollup plugin `rollup-plugin-monaco-editor` in the plugins array. However, I am still getting this issue.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    monaco({ languages: ['javascript'] }),
  ],
});
```

Is there any proper way to import `monaco-editor` into a Vite 2 project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest release (`2.0.0-beta.59`) it is fixed.

You can now add the environment workers without any further configuration (ref: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/1791)

```js
import editorWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker'
import jsonWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker?worker'
import cssWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker?worker'
import htmlWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker?worker'
import tsWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker?worker'

self.MonacoEnvironment = {
  getWorker(_, label) {
    if (label === 'json') {
      return new jsonWorker()
    }
    if (label === 'css' || label === 'scss' || label === 'less') {
      return new cssWorker()
    }
    if (label === 'html' || label === 'handlebars' || label === 'razor') {
      return new htmlWorker()
    }
    if (label === 'typescript' || label === 'javascript') {
      return new tsWorker()
    }
    return new editorWorker()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is ok in dev build, but in production build at current version (v2.1.2), `Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined` is raised on page load.
So in addition to the accepted answer, `build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks` needs to be added to `vite.config.js` like the following.

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
const prefix = `monaco-editor/esm/vs`;
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: {
          jsonWorker: [`${prefix}/language/json/json.worker`],
          cssWorker: [`${prefix}/language/css/css.worker`],
          htmlWorker: [`${prefix}/language/html/html.worker`],
          tsWorker: [`${prefix}/language/typescript/ts.worker`],
          editorWorker: [`${prefix}/editor/editor.worker`],
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: good job i miss that on prod